# Translucent text as a background of minipage

Tags: tables, minipage, watermark

I would be happy, if somebody helps me to achieve this result -- make something like watermark but put it in my particular `minipage` (as on screenshot shown)

[image]

***Here is my code:***

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extreport}
\usepackage[left=0.5cm,right=0.5cm,
top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}
%------------------  
\usepackage{lstautogobble}  % Fix relative indenting
\usepackage{color}          % Code coloring
\usepackage{zi4}            % Nice font
  \definecolor{bluekeywords}{rgb}{0.13, 0.13, 1}
  \definecolor{greencomments}{rgb}{0, 0.5, 0}
  \definecolor{redstrings}{rgb}{0.9, 0, 0}
  \definecolor{graynumbers}{rgb}{0.5, 0.5, 0.5}
  \usepackage{listings}
  \lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  columns=fullflexible,
  frame=single,
  breaklines=true,
  postbreak=\mbox{\textcolor{red}{$\hookrightarrow$}\space},
  }
%------------------  


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
  \begin{tabular}{c | c}
  \begin{minipage}[m]{0.4\textwidth}
  some text or picture
  \end{minipage}
  &
  \begin{minipage}[m]{0.55\textwidth}
  \begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\scriptsize]
  some text
  \end{lstlisting}
  \end{minipage}
  \end{tabular}
  \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

***Perfect solution for me:***

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extreport}
\usepackage[left=0.5cm,right=1.5cm,
top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}

%------------------  
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lstautogobble}  % Fix relative indenting
\usepackage{color}          % Code coloring
\usepackage{zi4}            % Nice font
  \definecolor{bluekeywords}{rgb}{0.13, 0.13, 1}
  \definecolor{greencomments}{rgb}{0, 0.5, 0}
  \definecolor{redstrings}{rgb}{0.9, 0, 0}
  \definecolor{graynumbers}{rgb}{0.5, 0.5, 0.5}
  \usepackage{listings}
  \lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  columns=fullflexible,
  frame=single,
  breaklines=true,
  postbreak=\mbox{\textcolor{red}{$\hookrightarrow$}\space},
  }
%------------------  



\begin{document}

  \begin{tabular}{c | c}
  
\begin{minipage}[m]{0.4\textwidth}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
\node (0,0) {
  \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image}
  };
\node [opacity=0.05] (0,0) {\scalebox{10.0}{\textcolor{red}{3.1}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
  &
  \begin{minipage}[m]{0.5\textwidth}
  \begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\scriptsize]
  \begin{minipage}[m]{0.4\textwidth}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
\node (0,0) {
  \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image}
  };
\node [opacity=0.2] (0,0) {\scalebox{10.0}{\textcolor{red}{3.1}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
  \end{lstlisting}
  \end{minipage}
  \end{tabular}
  

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have left out code that produces the chapter headings and section headings (section `3.1` in this case), but guessing that part, you can advance backwards manually (that is, move in the negative direction) to re-arrange the positions of items vertically, and then use overlap etc.

Using `fontspec` package to set the colour and opacity of the font, and `titlesec` package to apply it to the section label, as an illustration:

[image: label overlap]

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extreport}
\usepackage[left=0.5cm,right=0.5cm,
top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}
%------------------  
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\fmysec{Noto Serif}[Scale=5,Colour=red,Opacity=0.3]
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlelabel{{\fmysec \thetitle}}

\usepackage{lstautogobble}  % Fix relative indenting
%\usepackage{color}          % Code coloring
\usepackage{zi4}            % Nice font
  \definecolor{bluekeywords}{rgb}{0.13, 0.13, 1}
  \definecolor{greencomments}{rgb}{0, 0.5, 0}
  \definecolor{redstrings}{rgb}{0.9, 0, 0}
  \definecolor{graynumbers}{rgb}{0.5, 0.5, 0.5}
  \usepackage{listings}
  \lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  columns=fullflexible,
  frame=single,
  breaklines=true,
  postbreak=\mbox{\textcolor{red}{$\hookrightarrow$}\space},
  }
%------------------  


\begin{document}
\chapter{x}
\chapter{x}
\chapter{\ \\[-1em] Code, listings, minted \ldots}
\section{\hspace{1.5in}\llap{\normalsize\mdseries\raisebox{7em}{Code listing using \textit{minted} in \colorbox{red!7}{Beamer}}}}
%\begin{table}[h!] % table float not needed
\vspace{-5em}
  \begin{tabular}{c | c}
  \begin{minipage}[m]{0.4\textwidth}
  some text or picture
  \end{minipage}
  &
  \begin{minipage}[m]{0.55\textwidth}
  \begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\scriptsize]
  some text
  \end{lstlisting}
  \end{minipage}
  \end{tabular}
  
%  \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank You for Your answer, but as I understand it (your code) works with XeLaTex and I use PdfLaTeX thats why it does not work for me or I do not know how to make it work properly on PdfLaTeX ?

Comment: (a) "does not work" is not a useful description - post a new question with the code and error message. (b) commenting out `fontspec` and `newfontfamily`, and using `fontsize` and `color` commands directly, and then compiling with pdflatex, xelatex and lualatex, shows that xelatex and lualatex gives much better output than pdflatex regarding the oversize font. (c) Running under xelatex and lualatex is not difficult. Ask a question if you need help with that. (d) How does the document you got the screen image from do it? With some package?

Comment: The titelabel command becomes: `\titlelabel{{\fontsize{120}{5}\selectfont\color{red!8} \thetitle}}`. You can change the values and see the effect, if you want.

Comment: Is there more manual way to do it ? I mean just place transparent text overlay in minipage? couse if I use Your example I have a kind of mess in document

Comment: I heve made my example  screen image with photoshop package)
And also your example does not overlap pictures